# How to use "the day of the week" properly?

Tags: prepositions, time, time-words

After having done some research, here are my understandings of the uses of "the day of the week", but I am not sure I am right.

[First Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time):

> with a singular day of the week to refer to **one occasion:**
>
> *I’ve got to go to London on Friday.*
>
> with a plural day of the week to refer to **repeated events**:
>
> *The office is closed on Fridays.* (every Friday) In informal
>   situations, we often leave out on before plural days:
>
> *Do you work Saturdays?*

[Second Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/Monday):

> Normally, "**Monday**", etc are nouns. However, In American English,
>   "**Monday**" could be an adverb & "**Monday (adv)**=on Monday"
>
> *I'll ring you Monday*
>
> Similarly, "**Mondays (adv)**=on Mondays"
>
> *The restaurant is closed Mondays*

[Third Source](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/monday)

> **a Monday (=one of the Mondays in the year)**
>
> *My birthday’s on a Monday this year.*

So, based on the 3 above rules, **I would think these following sentences are correct:**

> I often do yoga on Mondays (repeated event)
>
> I often do yoga Mondays (repeated event)
>
> I will do yoga on Monday / next Monday (one occasion)
>
> I went to Paris on Monday (one occasion)

However, I don't understand, why oxford dictionary has these example

**On Monday(s) (= Every Monday) I do yoga.**

*On Monday I do yoga.* (repeated event) ---> is this correct?

*I always do yoga on a Monday.* (repeated event)  ---> is this correct?

*I work Monday to Friday.* (repeated event)  ---> is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

In casual conversation:

> > On Monday I do yoga

could mean either this coming Monday, as in:

> > I can't come to the concert because on (this coming) Monday I do yoga

or every Monday:

> > I can attend choir practice any day except (each) Monday when I do yoga.

It's correct to state:

> > I always do yoga on a Monday (repeated event - although the *a* is often elided.

Regarding work on weekdays, people will say either:

> > I work Monday to Friday (repeated event)

or

> > I work Mondays to Fridays (repeated event).

Both are quite acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> On Monday I do yoga. (repeated event) ---> is this correct?

If a native speaker is looking at a calendar, say, and referring not to a particular Monday, but to Monday as one of the seven days of the week, weeks which recur throughout the month and year, the speaker might say

> I can't have lunch with you this Monday, next Monday, or any Monday. I
>   do yoga *on Monday*.

The meaning is "Monday is the day of the week that I set aside for yoga, every week."

> I always do yoga on a Monday. (repeated event) ---> is this correct?

That means:

> Whenever I do yoga, you can be sure that, whatever the week or time of year, if you check your phone, it will say "Monday".

(That's an explanation, by the way, not a paraphrase.)

> I work Monday to Friday. (repeated event) ---> is this correct?

My work-week extends from Monday of the week to Friday of the week, week in, week out.

Comment: I would prefer "I always do yoga on Mondays" which sounds much better & popular

Comment: I'm not offering any personal preferences here, @Tom, just explaining to you what the native speaker would mean.